# Is there an API or any other method to automate the submission process?

Tags: iphone, app-store, xcodebuild

I have a number of apps which are similar in functionality and UI. I create the user interface by picking up variables from a .plist file. For instance, I save the source of the API from where I pick up the data.

Creating a new app involves just changing the values in the .plist file and rebuilding the app, and finally submitting it to the App Store. Also, I need to create Ad-Hoc provision files and build test releases too.

I wish to automate this process. For this I need to:

1. Build the app through the command line interface.
2. Upload the binary and other required files/information (app icon, description, etc.) to iTunes Connect.

Any pointers where I should look?

Comment: I just saw appmakr.com. I was thinking on similar lines. How do they submit the Apps? Curl or standard POST?

Comment: On a personal note, please do not spam the App Store with "Call Jim", "Call Bob", etc. type applications.  The store is crowded enough as it is.  If you're doing something like a travel guide that handles multiple locations, or e-books, consider using in-application purchasing and only submit one core application that would contain all of that content.

Comment: Well I hate them apps as much as you do. I really just want to automate as much of the process as possible. Specially during the initial design and layout phase.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888122/how-to-upload-an-ios-app-to-the-app-store-via-command-line

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Building your Xcode projects can be automated by using the command line tool `xcodebuild` that Apple provides.

As far as automating the app creation process goes, Apple has not exposed this functionality outside of the Xcode GUI. You can still automate this and there are two options.

1. Use Automator to create a script
   that replays all the actions a human
   would perform to create a new
   project.  Parts of this replay
   script like the project name etc.
   can be customized and
   programmatically fed to the script.
   A disadvantage of this method is
   that this will actually run on the
   GUI and will be slow.
2. If you want to do it all through the
   command line, you will have to
   reverse engineer the contents of the
   Xcode project file that has the
   extension .xcodeproj. It's a
   compressed file and contains a few
   XML configuration files for the
   entire project. There is no public
   documentation on the contents of
   these XML files.

For automating the submission process, you will need a script that talks to itunesconnect.apple.com. This is where you would submit your app to the App Store. Checkout [this page](http://developer.apple.com/support/iphone/connect/) for more info on iTunes Connect.
A browser automation tool will be helpful here though you could roll your custom script that talks to iTunes Connect over HTTP.

To summarize, the only thing that can be used readily out of the box is the `xcodebuild` tool. Everything else has to be reverse engineered.

Comment: Thanks Anurag! But I guess posting the apps to iTunesConnect would pose problems in the future. What if Apple changes the site? There must be a better way out there.

Comment: That's true, but it cannot be helped unless Apple opens up some sort of APIs for iTunes Connect. Among the available options a custom script is probably better than using a browser automation tool as GUI changes should not affect your script. It will break, however, if the form elements like the name attribute changes. To minimize this damage, you could put all the items required on iTunes Connect inside a XML or some other configuration file, and map it to your actual data.

Comment: @Anurag - what do you mean on #1? Using automator's "watch me do"? Does this ever worked for anyone? It never worked for me, I mean, I never say this function working correctly for the simplest web page or I am not using it correctly.

Comment: @Digital Robot - I meant a combination of the Automator along with some hand-coded AppleScript. Automator alone won't get you too far.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888122/how-to-upload-an-ios-app-to-the-app-store-via-command-line

Answer (score 11):

It's 2016, and now we have the [iTunesConnect Transporter](http://itunespartner.apple.com/en/movies/faq/Transporter_Getting%20Set%20Up#!) command line tool with a [quick start guide here](http://wmiphone.files.wordpress.com/2013/07/itunes_store_transporter_quick_start_guide_v2.pdf).

Also, have a look at this OSS project that wraps the Transporter tools (and others) in a friendly way:

https://fastlane.tools

Comment: Those tools are amazing! Every iOS developer should get to know those. Sometimes I spend days over submitting apps which should be minutes now.

Comment: Also, if you want a cloud provider for all this, check out Bitrise.io - http://bitrise.io