# How to upload an iOS app to the app store via command line

Tags: iphone, macos, app-store

As part of the countinues integration process of my iPhone application, I want to create a process that will automatically upload the app (.ipa) file to the apple app store. I already managed to create the package and validate it.
Is there a way to upload the ipa file to the appstore via command line?

Comment: You could try automating or AppleScripting Xcode, and call that automation script from the command line.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The previous reply does not work with the new iTunes Connect any more.

You need to use the `iTunes Transporter` to upload your app to iTunes Connect. Check out the source code of [deliver](https://fastlane.tools/deliver) on GitHub: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/itunes_transporter.rb

You can use [deliver](https://fastlane.tools/deliver) to automatically upload new updates to the App Store: https://fastlane.tools/deliver

Answer (score 33):

1. Make sure you have an application in "waiting to upload" state.
2. Create a new keychain Item Named: Xcode:itunesconnect.apple.com provide your credentials to itunes connect.
3. From the command line: `xcrun -sdk iphoneos Validation -online -upload -verbose "path to ipa"`

Comment: This is perfect. I've lots of clients and customers. I want to upload apps on behalf of my clients/customers, how can I create respective key chain items and provide them during "xcrun" command?

Comment: you can create a ad-hoc key before running xcrun and discart it after the upload is finished
`security add-generic-password -s Xcode:itunesconnect.apple.com -a LOGIN -w PASSWORD -U`
`xcrun -sdk iphoneos Validation -online -upload -verbose "path to ipa"`
`security delete-generic-password  -s Xcode:itunesconnect.apple.com -a LOGIN`

Comment: is this actual? I am trying to send via command line ready built IPA file, and it is giving back some error.

Comment: I get2014-02-07 14:08:20.044 Validation[705:1207] *** Error: Unable to persist validation configuration: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file couldn’t be saved."
warning: There are no applications pre-configured in iTunesConnect.  On-line application validation was skipped.

Comment: @MR.GEWA You didn't follow the first step

Comment: @tomer-shirini i have added the generic-password, it's there, even the second command  when it's run, it's ask permission to keychain.

Comment: @MR.GEWA you need to add an new version to an app via iTunes Connect.

Comment: new version is already added. and the app status is changed to WAITING FOR UPLOAD.

Comment: I have checked, the problem was the credentials. now another problem came up. when you have more than 1 app which is waiting for upload, it selects always 1st one, which is almost always wrong package. how to set app_id in command?

Comment: +1 For MR.GEWA's question. I'm not having problems now because we only have 1 app, but I'd like a solution I can always use.

Comment: @Dan2552 if you have several apps which wait for upload , just create a list of commands  ordering them via Alphabet by App Title , so you can upload one by one as the order is in Application Loader Select Menu.

Comment: @TomerShiri do you know a way how via command line to  mark the app as "Waiting For Uoload" ??? I would like to automate the process in the step before uploading. Now I have to go one by one 100 apps and mark for upload to update them .... :((((

Comment: WARNING for anyone finding this advice some time later, as I just did in Sep 2014, http://mobilecraft.tumblr.com/post/23486904489/command-line-ios-app-validation-and-upload claimed  that as of Feb 2013 "Apple finally acknowledged these tools are not documented and said they are not supported for command line."  I have not verified their claim.

Comment: The "Validation" tool has been removed since Xcode 7.1

Answer (score 5):

**UPLOAD IPA TO TESTFLIGHT**

```
altool --upload-app -f "${APP_NAME}.ipa" -u $APP_STORE_USERNAME -p $APP_STORE_PASSWORD
```

> To use `altool` from anywhere in the terminal you could add it to your
>   PATH env variable by typing in terminal:
>
> **Previous to Xcode 11:**
>
> ```
> MacBook-Pro:~ denis$ export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Applications/Application\ Loader.app/Contents/Frameworks/ITunesSoftwareService.framework/Support/
> MacBook-Pro:~ denis$ source ~/.bash_profile
> ```
>
> **From Xcode 11 and later: (`altool` has changed location)**
>
> ```
> MacBook-Pro:~ denis$ export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/
> MacBook-Pro:~ denis$ source ~/.bash_profile
> ```

Comment: altool is now in /Applications/Xcode.app//Contents/Developer/usr/bin/altool

Comment: @EionRobb Thank you for helping out updating this old answer :) I just put the information for the new location since Xcode 11

Answer (score 2):

You should use application loader tool: altool --upload-app -f file -u username [-p password] [--output-format xml]

As describe in:
https://help.apple.com/itc/apploader/#/apdATD1E53-D1E1A1303-D1E53A1126

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Transporter](https://help.apple.com/itc/transporteruserguide/en.lproj/static.html) directly to get away from fastlane if desired. It can also be installed on any OS so container based (docker) uploads are theoretically possible.

Once you have it setup try something like:

```
iTMSTransporter -m upload -u <usename_email> -p <password> -k 10000 -itc_provider <provider_id> -assetFile MyApp.ipa -assetDescription AppStoreInfo.plist
```

The provider ID is something you will need to look up using the transporter's `-m provider` command