# How to upload an Android app to the app store via command line

Tags: android, command-line, automation, google-play

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11888122/1331671) for `iOS` and basically worry about the same thing for `Android`.

As part of the countinues integration process of my `Android` application, I want to create a process that will automatically upload the app (`.apk`) file to the `Google PlayStore`.

I found [this website](http://geosoft.no/development/android.html) explaining how to create an `.apk` automated.

So I wonder if there is a way to upload the `.apk` file to the `PlayStore` via command line?

Comment: Nothing that is documented and supported.

Comment: To upload an app to Apple App Store, you should do it on Xcode. But for Android Play Store, you have to use Google Play Developer Console, which is a website. So, i don't think it's possible to publish an app by using command line.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no way to do this at the moment. You have to use the Google Developer Console to release your application.

Answer (score 3):

These days you can do this fairly easily with [Gradle Play Publisher](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher):

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.github.triplet.play' version 'x.x.x'
}

android {
    ...
}

play {
    serviceAccountCredentials = file("your-credentials.json")
}
```

Then it's as simple as running `./gradlew publishApk`.

Answer (score 1):

This API should do it, as long as you are not publishing new app, but new version of an existing app. I've not used it yet though.
https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/

You could also use Jenkins, there is Jenkins plug-in for this purpose: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Google+Play+Android+Publisher+Plugin