# Command line ios app upload with Xcode 6

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos, app-store, xcode6

We have been using the answer provided here ([How to upload an iOS app to the app store via command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888122/how-to-upload-an-ios-app-to-the-app-store-via-command-line)) by Tomer Shiri to automate the uploading of our apps to the iTunes Connect using a script. This has been worked fine with Xcode 5.X but now we have installed Xcode 6 this fails when run.

We believe the script we have made is falling over on the line that contains the xcrun command with the error of:

users-mac-mini:~ user$ sh /Users/user/Desktop/Master\ Upload\ Script.sh 
sh: create.sh: No such file or directory
error: Unknown application extension '.' - expected '.app' or '.ipa'

Does anyone know if the xcrun command has changed in Xcode 6? and if so what would be the equivalent command that incorporates any changes?

Thanks

James

EDIT: as a side thought I have seen a few comments around the internet that suggest that apple has confirmed that this is an undocumented tool. With that in mind, is anyone with decompiling\ disassembly skills able and willing to pull this apart and find a list of the CLI options for the xcode 6 version of the xcrun binary?

Comment: Looks like the Validator tool no longer accepts the -upload or -online commands. It is interpreting them as the IPA and blowing up. A similar issue and workaround is available on the [Shenzhen repo](https://github.com/nomad/shenzhen/issues/147).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @JoeMasilotti I shall get our coder to have a look through that link when he gets back from some training he is on this week.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888122/how-to-upload-an-ios-app-to-the-app-store-via-command-line

Try the answer at the above link.