# Importing Code From Online

Tags: objective-c, import

I know its a bit of a far fetched question.

But is it possible to import code from online, like say I had a .h and .m file on my website server and in the code I wanted to use it would I be able to import it? And How?

I ask this because it makes it loads easier to update an app if all they need to do is reload the app and the app changes to the latest version.

Comment: Interesting question, but unless you're talking about an Obj-C interpreter, I don't see how you'd make this work. You would still need to compile against the iOS SDK before deploying the code.

Comment: the only way to do this is with a web / hybrid app. Assuming this is for the app store, Apple would reject an app which can be updated from outside the app store by downloading executable native code

Comment: Not likely. The user would still have to have a compiler and the source code for your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about a Mac OS X application, then *yes* it's possible. No need to share your source code, just compile on the server and have the app download the new binary.

However, if your App needs to go through the App Store, which is necessary for iOS apps, then this surely is *not* possible. The only thing you can do is streamline the submission process as much as possible ([see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005517/automating-iphone-app-submission-process)).

If you love the idea of being able to push new code at any time, consider making a web app. There's lots of stuff you can do these days.

Comment: It wasn't really a problem if it couldn't be done I was just wondering whether it could be, it would save a lot of time if you could bypass the App Store by just having GUI releases. Although I suppose thinking about it, the app needs to compile in order to become an IPA (Yes I was on about iPhone), so the root files which you code in Xcode get compiled into a IPA format or something like that. It doesn't matter anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% (maybe 95%) sure but I think storing objc code online to keep it auto-upgradable is not possible since the app isn't able to rebuild itself.

But if you want you could do a generic app that firstly fetches an XML/plist (for example) stored online to retrieve data and the app is set to read it and present different behaviours depending on that, but you'll have to code it previously in a generic way to support dynamic changes.

Hope this helps.